# Bootstrap form not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just found out that my forms on these pages are not working.

http://www.abado.dk/modtag-tre-tilbud/

http://www.abado.dk/kontakt/

http://www.abado.dk/bliv-partner/

I really don't have any idea what is wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is on your `padding: 25px 15px;` in  `.form-control`

you in put height is **34px**  at the same time you are using padding-top(**25px**) + padding-bottom(**25px**) = **50px** with in the **34px**

Add this in to css properties

```
.form-control{
    height: auto;
}
```

**or** adjust padding value

Comment: @Casperlarsen because `box-sizing:border-box;` property includes padding and border as size. you can add `box-sizing: content-box` which I don't recommend 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing